# my character wont climb and just falls in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im very new to Unity and C#
I have been trying to make my character climb on ladders for hours and tried 20+ diffrent scripts but nothing is working.I am putting the script on the collider around the ladder(the ladder is part of the tiles)i even added a spirit behind the tiles where the ladders and put the collider around them but nothing the character just falls(i have put the collider as a trigger)again i am new this was a code i found that a lot of people liked but it seemed not to work for me 
here is the ladder code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ladder : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameObject playerOBJ;
    bool canClimb = false;
    float speed = 1;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            canClimb = true;
            playerOBJ = coll.gameObject;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision coll2)
    {
        if (coll2.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            canClimb = false;
            playerOBJ = null;
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (canClimb)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                playerOBJ.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                playerOBJ.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: What do you mean it just falls? Can you move your character at all? Do you have any collider on the ground to stop your character from passing through?

Comment: yes i have,the ladders lead underground and there is hole where the character has to go down and up from but when i try going down the ladders i just fall in the hole and cant get up(climb up the ladders)the character can move left,right,jump and crouch

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the gravity on your character rigidbody while climbing otherwise the gravity will always take your character down.

You can access your character rigidbody like this:

`playerRB = playerOBJ.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`

you can change the gravity to 0:

`playerRB.gravityScale = 0;` and back to 1 when you need to.

For instance disable the gravity anytime your character hit the ladder collider and enable the gravity when you press "A" or "D" to make your character fall from the ladder.

Comment: I still havent learned the basic of C# (ill be doing o soon)where in the code should i add this....i really am new

Comment: You can add above code where 'canClimb' is true. I suggest looking at Unity's beginner tutorial for scripting.

Comment: thank you i want to learn as much as i can about C#,Unity and game development in general i dont know why but after fixing a problem i get so happy i forget how angry i was and can do that for hours id appreciate any advice for beginners like myself